# CodeDomProvider.CreateCompiler() is obsolete

Tags: c#, obsolete

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
ICodeCompiler MyCompiler = codeProvider.CreateCompiler();
CompilerParameters myParameters = new CompilerParameters();
myParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
myParameters.OutputAssembly = @"prog.exe";
myParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
CompilerResults results = myCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(myParameters,"prog.txt");
```

How can I write this code to eliminate this warning:

> System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateCompiler()' is obsolete: '"Callers should not use the ICodeCompiler interface and should instead use the methods directly on the CodeDomProvider class. Those inheriting from CodeDomProvider must still implement this interface, and should exclude this warning or also obsolete this method.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead:

```
CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
```

Extended:

```
if (CodeDomProvider.IsDefinedLanguage(language))
{
    CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider(language);
    // ...
}
else
    Console.WriteLine("ERROR");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CSharpCodeProvider codeProvider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters myParameters = new CompilerParameters();
myParameters.GenerateExecutable = true;
myParameters.OutputAssembly = @"prog.exe";
myParameters.TreatWarningsAsErrors = false;
CompilerResults results = codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(myParameters, "prog.txt");
```

Comment: @eddie_cat remove `codeProvider.CreateCompiler()` code and use directly `codeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile` instead